# Using a Java written @Controller in Grails

Tags: java, spring, grails

I have created a Java class in Groovy Project in src/java folder.
I have used @Controller annotation to create a REST Webservice.
Code look like this

and then I configured component in resources.groovy

```
xmlns context: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'
    context.'component-scan'('base-package': 'com.**.**')
```

which matches package of the above piece of code.

When I'm trying to invoke service using  URL its not able to recognize this.

Comment: Can you describe why you use a Java class instead of a plain Grails controller? What Grails version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Component scanning is already enabled by Grails, so delete yours. If you want annotated Spring beans to be discovered and registered, add one or more package names to the `grails.spring.bean.packages` list in `Config.groovy`, e.g.

```
grails.spring.bean.packages = ['com.foo.bar', 'some.other.package']
```